# How to show group header in next page if details is on the next page?

Tags: crystal-reports

here is my problem in crystal report on how to show group header label on next page of details.

Here is the example:

I have `Second Semester, 2010-2011` as a `header` in `Page 2`

**Page 2 Image**
[image]

**Page 3 Image**
[image]

but on the next page which is page 3 the details continue.

I want to show `Second Semester, 2010-2011` on the next page if its details continue to next page.

How to do this.

Please help me..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to `Group Expert` then
Select the `options` tab and check `Repeat group header on each page`

There are other crystal report that you can find that in `Change Group` then `option` and then check `Repeat group header on each page`

Comment: Thank you Wicked Programmer so much.